# Bluetooth dongle not working if two USB hubs are connected to the PC

Tags: windows, usb, bluetooth, usb-hub

I have [ASUS Bluetooth 5.0 USB dongle](https://www.asus.com/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/USB-BT500/) (USB 2.0). I used it with the passive USB 3.0 hub of my monitor. I've recently purchased another (desk-attached) USB 3.0 hub (also passive).

My (5+ yrs old) motherboard has both **USB 3.0** ports (blue, "native", Intel Chipset, MoBo internal connectors -> front panel) and **USB 3.1** ports (teal, ASMedia USB3.1 eXtensible Host Controller, rear MoBo panel).

For some strange reason, the Bluetooth dongle **does not work if **both** hubs are connected** to the two rear USB3.1 ports correspondingly (ASMedia controller).

[image]

By *works*, I mean that I'm able to connect other Bluetooth devices (like speakers) to the PC and that Windows Device Manager looks like this:

[image]

---

When **both** hubs are connected to the **two rear USB3.1 ports**, and I then connect the USB dongle, the Device manager looks like

[image]

and Windows says that `Bluetooth is turned off`.
Bluetooth Troubleshooter says that `This device does not have Bluetooth capability`.

This also happens when Windows boots with both hubs connected and BT dongle plugged in one of them.

---

If I disconnect **any** of the hubs (either the one in the monitor, or the new one), the dongle starts working (both if left connected to the other hub or re-plugged): Windows discovers the dongle, shows that `This device has Bluetooth capability` and connects to Bluetooth speakers.
I can then reconnect the hub I disconnected, and the dongle continues to work, the audio is not interrupted.

*Other devices (USB Flash drives, cardreaders, USB RF Mice etc) work fine with both hubs*.

---

**I've partially resolved this problem** by using "chipset-native" USB3.0 ports:

[image]

If I connect one of the hubs to "chipset-native" front USB3.0 ports, and the other to the rear USB 3.1 ports, then everything works fine.

It seems that this problem is related to inability(?) of ASMedia USB3.1 eXtensible Host Controller to deal with two USB3 hubs.

I would like to hear if someone has experienced this as well and **whether this problem can be  solved with software-only means** (without having to install extra rear USB 3.0 expansion slot, plugged to MoBo's "chipset-native" USB3.0 connectors).

Comment: I have solve this (Desktop) with powered hub plugged into monitor and everything else (ALL else) plugged into the hub. Nothing else into the monitor.

Comment: have I answered your question?

Comment: @John, thank you very much for your idea! I would definitely consider using powered USB hubs in the future, but for now I would like to determine, if there's something weird with my ASMedia controller, or if this could be solved by software means. Thus I would like to hear more answers :)